# Morris Line graph deformed after being hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, graph, morris.js

I have setup a morris line graph in my page like this:

```
var chart = new Morris.Line({
        element: 'myfirstchart',

        xkey: 'Date',

        ykeys: ['Sales'],


        labels: ['Sales'],
        resize: true,
        redraw: true,
        xLabels: 'day',
        parseTime: false
    });
```

And upon displaying the results after a post (in done method of jquery's post) I do this:

```
 chart.setData(data.lineData);
 chart.redraw();
 $(window).trigger("resize");
```

But the graph looks ugly and deformed completely like this:

[image]

The graph itselef is hidden in a div which is then displayed upon showing the results...

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a well known weakness of Morris Chart. You can go through by resizing the svg element with its parent element width

```
var t_w = $('#myfirstchart').parent().width();
$('#myfirstchart svg').width(t_w);
chart.redraw();
```